# Adding numbers in a matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix

I have a two-dimensional array, and I want to sum all the values in that array, where the value is not -1.
Suppose I have a matrix that has the following values:

```
0,1 = 1.68
1,2 = 1.74
2,0 = 1.61
3,4 = -1
...
```

I want to add the all the numbers that are not -1

What I did try, and which obviously doesn't work for me, is:

```
for(i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
  for(j=0; j<data.length; ++j) {
    if(data[i][j] != -1) {
      sum += data[i][j]+data[j][i]
    }
  }
}
```

In my case, if an index (n, m) = k then it is also true that index (m, n) = k.

So for example, if (n, m) = 1.74, then (m, n) = 1.74. That is why I need to do `data[i][j]+data[j][i]` in the code above

What I REALLY want as result, is this: `sum = (0,1 + 1,0) + (1,2 + 2,0) + (2,0 + 0,2)    =>    sum = 2*(1,68) + 2*(1,74) + 2*(1,68)`

What I get as result from my code above, is undefined.

I tried an alternative solution using .map (...), which according to the document, takes a function to map. But for now it is just a bit too complicated for me with the double array (I'm not experienced programmer yet)

`data.map((a,i) => a.map((n,j) => n+data[i][j]));`
I got an error here saying a not a function

Comment: still don't get it what is the real problem statement

Comment: if(data[i][j] != -!) -  are you sure this is correct? Shoudl it not be -1?

Comment: in the code you put if statement is not correct

Comment: What is `data[i][j] != -!` .. ?

Comment: Yeah, it is a typo, it should say data[i][j] != -1.  It is correct in my code, just here I made a typo. Thanks for pointing it out, fixing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested reduce

```js
 const data = [];
    var dt = [1,2,3]
    data[0] = dt;
    data[1] = dt;
    data[2] = dt;

var total = data.reduce((n,arr)=> n+arr.reduce((n,val)=>n+val), 0);

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you want to sum all the values in a square matrix. So even though (m,n) = (n,m) in your matrix, one simple way to sum the values is :

```
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        if (data[i][j] !== -1) sum += data[i][j];
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```

But if you want to do some calculation that take into account the fact that (m,n) = (n,m) in your matrix, you can try this:

```
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        if (data[i][j] !== -1) {
            if (i === j) sum += data[i][j];
            if (j < i) sum += 2*data[i][j];
        }
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```